# MySql,PHP error handling

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that takes inputs from the user and searches through the database.

Now depending on the inputs the result size can vary.

Query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$drop` WHERE `Stop Name` = '$input'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Result

```
$rows = $result->num_rows; 

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) {
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

    //Display Results

    for ($j = 0 ; $j <= 124 ; ++$j)  echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>"; 
}
```

this gives me an Undefined offset error for when their is less than 124 variables (Most that could possibly be displayed) to show.

Where in the code do I add the @ to ignore these errors.

Comment: Why not just use a `foreach` loop instead? Also, never ignore errors, solve them.

Comment: Don't use @ to hide error messages, try to solve the errors as first!

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 4):

You should **not simply suppress errors** like that.

Instead, stop looping when you have reached the end of the array:

```
for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($row) ; ++$j)  echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
```

**Side note:** you are using the same iterator `$j` for both loops. That won't work as expected.